# collision detection on non-full tiles in a Tilemap

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, collision-detection

If one creates a tile map from a tileset and there are tiles/squares that are not completely full, how Does on make these half filled tiles able to detect collision?

Its easy to select an area that is square and set it to e.g. collision yes

But how does one handle rounded edges that fill half a tile or a triangular shape that is just entering a tile?

Or does one create an entire layer and set it to collision yes that that tiles dont need to be check for collision?

Still, how does one detect the layer for collisions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole idea of a tile based system is that stuff fills an entire tile. You can apply normal collision detection approaches to tiles of course, or apply them on a per tile basis.

Some games allow buildings to fill a whole tile, but still have units traverse tiles. This is often done by taking the 4 corner points (and 4 points at the center of the sides) and checking if a line between a few of these points doesn't collide with anything, if that is true then units can travel these lines.

This is often pre-computed for every building that can occupy a tile.

Comment: Thanks. what if the tiles are made really small so that round edges will cover most of a tile and the detection will be more precise?

Comment: You can use small tiles, but how smaller the tiles are how more costly path finding will be, so you'll have to balance accuracy with speed.  The '4-corner' solution is cheaper than having 4 times as much tiles because this only changes the per-tile-formula of if something is reachable, but its a bit harder to get right. I would suggest that you play around a bit with both methods to see which one suits your game best :).